# How to view all unread emails from all inboxes in Outlook, similar to Windows Live Mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 and would like to see all the new email as they come in. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I think this can be set up through File -> Rules and Alerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found how to do it.

1. Select "Folder" tab and click "New Search Folder".
2. Select "Unread mail" and select mail box.
3. Click "Ok" and it will add a new search folder. Note: by default it will select search all unread messages in "Inbox" including the subfolders. If you want to refine the search, right click on the folder and click "Customize This Search Folder"
4. Right click on the new folder and add it to Favorites for easy access.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to make a folder for all unread mail across all inboxes, but this works for now.